# Beginner - Context Menu different function for different Buttons

Tags: java, android, arrays, contextmenu

Since I am new to Java and Android Studio Im working on a little App a Soundboard. So until now I coded a Soundboard with 2 Arrays Array of Buttons, and Array of Sounds.mp3

Now I am buildung a Context menu and it is also working well but until now my problem is the App is doing for each Button the same "function" of the context menu. But every button do have a different sound how can I get it working that it is also working like the Array/Button that for each button there is different Soundfile

```
public int[] buttonsas = {button1, R.id.button2, R.id.button3};
public int[] sounds = {R.raw.sound1, R.raw.sound2, R.raw.sound3};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



   for (int i = 0; i < buttonsas.length; i++) {
        Button contextMenuButton = (Button) findViewById(buttonsas[i]);
        registerForContextMenu(contextMenuButton);
    }

    MainMedia = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound1);
}
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    menu.setHeaderTitle("Context Menu");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Action 1");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Action 2");
}


@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if(item.getTitle().equals("Action 1")){function1(item.getItemId());}
    else if(item.getTitle().equals("Action 2"))                                            {function2(item.getItemId());}
    else {return false;}
    return true;
}

public void function1(int id){
    Toast.makeText(this, "function 1 called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
public void function2(int id){
    Toast.makeText(this, "function 2 called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code and comment in case you feel any difficulty

```
 //replace following in your onCreate method
 for (int i = 0; i < buttonsas.length; i++) {
            Button contextMenuButton = (Button) findViewById(buttonsas[i]);
            contextMenuButton.setText("Action "+i);
            registerForContextMenu(contextMenuButton);
        }
```

And

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    menu.setHeaderTitle("Context Menu");
    Button buttonView = (Button) v; 
    menu.add(0, buttonView .getId(), 0, buttonView.getText());
}
```

`

Comment: Thanks about 2 min ago I solved my own Problem hehe :P but I also tried this one and it is also working well :)